# How is FM modulation is achieved using a single BJT

Tags: rf, bjt, modulation, frequency-modulation

I want to understand how this circuit achieve frequency modulation. The BJT is a 2N3904. I found that millers effect comes into play and varies the frequency of the tank circuit about a center frequency of the tank circuit.
I want to understand this in details and how to design circuits like this. How to calculate the parameters and their roles.

[image: FM modulation circuit]

Comment: 2N3004 is an SCR. Did you mean 2N3904?

Comment: Sorry, typo. didn't notice.

Comment: Rotate your image before Olin shows up and downvotes you for having to tilt his head to read it.

Comment: I uploaded a rotated image but it's not rotated when shown here. I am uploading from my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L1 and C1 form a resonant tank circuit - this produces the main frequency of the oscillator. Positive feedback from collector to emitter via C2 ensures oscillation quite close to the natural resonant frequency formed by L1 and C1.

The other factor is the reverse voltage between base and collector. There are components missing on your diagram that bias the base to a nominal voltage of about 2V and that reverse voltage to the collector defines the value of the transistor's internal miller capacitor. This miller capacitor is voltage dependent and with the base voltage variations this capacitor retunes L1 and C1 in sync with the audio signal applied to the base. Hence, the base voltage frequency modulates the oscillator.

It's not a great FM modulator but it does work providing the AC signal at the collector isn't too big in terms of volts peak to peak.

Comment: How does the miller's capacitence tune the tank circuit frequency? I want to form a equation of this tuning.And does the modulated frequency swing both above and below the natural frquency of the tank.

Comment: The base voltage can be regarded as AC ground from the perspective of the collector voltage so, the miller capacitance is in effect to ground (from the collector) but, ground or Vcc have the same potential so, in effect, and without fear of any significant approximation, the miller capacitor is in parallel with C1

Comment: didn't understand this part "ground or Vcc have same potential"

Comment: They have the same AC potential!

Comment: One more query... is this circuit good enough to transmit audio, does it modulate linearly or is there any non linearity.

Comment: It's fairly crappy but will work.